# What is the "B" in AがB in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> 最寄りがいっしょのわたしに一言も話さず黙殺する程度のコミュ力の持ち主がわたしの高校の生徒会長？

If A is 最寄り(Nearest person) then what is B? I'm confused in this case because I'm not sure if に can be attached to the end of a complete logical clause if B in this case is いっしょのわたし so that the sentence would roughly translate to something like "The nearest person is me に". It sounds unlikely to me and I'm leaning more towards 最寄り meaning "the other person closest to me" and B is "黙殺する" and いっしょのわたしに is the target of the action as part of a modifying clause.

Comment: How did you come up with that definition of 最寄り?  Hint: Isn't a train ride mentioned in the context?

Comment: @l'électeur Its definition in the dictionary is "Nearest" so I just guess its meaning as such. Sometimes in this novel, "最寄り駅" is used to refer to the nearest station that both of the characters go by but I'm not sure what the sentence would mean if 最寄り means the closest station in this case

Comment: @l'électeur. Now that I have been thinking about this sentence with 最寄り being "the nearest station", I think I know the answer now. 最寄りがいしょ is the modifying clause to わたし, which then translate to "me who [nearest station is the same]". Hopefully, someone can let me know if this way of thinking is correct. I'm still not too sure since this is the first time I have seen a modifying clause with が not used with a verb as the B part

Answer (score 1):

> If A is 最寄り(Nearest person) then what is B?

Your "if" scenario is highly unprobable. Having said that, if you are seeking for the answer for such hypothetical scenario, let me know and I'll edit the answer. Here I explain ignoring your "if" statement.

最寄り probably means 最寄り（の）駅 (station) or バス停 (bus stop). Some wrongly assume 最寄り is limited to train stations, but it can be attached to many things, such as 最寄りの郵便局 (your nearest post office). But when we casually say 最寄りどこ？ (where's your "moyori?") we mean "where's the station/bus-stop closest to your home?".

The sentence can be interpreted somewhat like the following:

*This person shares the same 最寄り (e.g. train station) with me, but this person never talks to me. Such non-social person is the student council president of my school?*

To be fair, I don't think you need to be chatty or have コミュ力 to become student council.

Comment: Thank you, 最寄り being the nearest person is not a hypothesis that I want to get an answer for but it's just what I thought 最寄り meant, which I have realized I was probably wrong and wrote something above under the original question to explain my new understandings. What confused me in this sentence was the fact that I didn't really know what 最寄り really meant until now and that this is the first time I have seen が be used in a modifying clause like this